# specify priors in multi-label Naive Bayes in python scikit-learn

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, naivebayes, multilabel-classification, scikit-multilearn

I am working on a **multi-label** classification. I used GaussianNB function on python scikit-learn. The target is an array with (N, L) shape, where L is the number of classes and N is the number of observations.

I used three ways to deal with multi-label case:

1. binary relevance
2. chain model
3. label powerset

I have a prior distribution for L classes, which is an array of (L,) shape. I tried to incorporate this prior distribution into GaussianNB through priors parameter like this

```
classifier = BinaryRelevance(GaussianNB(priors = prior_dist))
```

However, it returns the following error

```
ValueErrors: number of priors must match number of classes
```

What is the correct way to specify priors into GaussianNB in a multi-label case?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't added support for this yet in scikit-multilearn, but it seems fairly easy to add - could you put it as a [feature request in scikit-multilearn](https://github.com/scikit-multilearn/scikit-multilearn/issues)? I think I have an idea how to add this, but we can track the issue further in github.